# $G$ a set. When does a pair of subgroups of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ define "some" left and right multiplications?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

If $G$ is a (possibly infinite) group, left and right multiplications establish the subgroups $\Theta:=\lbrace \theta_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ and $\Gamma:=\lbrace \gamma_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, such that $G \cong \Theta$ and $G \cong \Gamma$.

I'm wondering about the contrary: assume $G$ to be a (possibly infinite) set and suppose we can establish a pair of subgroups $\Theta:=\lbrace \theta_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ and $\Gamma:=\lbrace \gamma_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, such that:

i) $\theta_a(b)=\gamma_b(a)$ for all $a,b \in G$;

ii) $\theta_a\gamma_b=\gamma_b\theta_a$ for all $a,b \in G$.

Can we say that $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ completely define *some* left and right multiplications, turning $G$ into *some* group? [i) would ensure the identity $ab=ab$, while ii) the associativity.]

Comment: I'm sorry. Are you assuming associativity or not?

Comment: Not assumimg; I'm hoping to get it by the condition ii).

Comment: No: just start from a group nontrivial group $G$, and consider subgroups of $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$.

Comment: One way to make it work is to assume only (ii), and that the actions of both $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ are simply transitive.

Comment: If you set $ab:=\theta_a(b)$ which group axiom are you struggling with?

Comment: Just to clarify my question. Take $G$ finite set; define $\rho \in \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ by $\rho(a_k):=a_{k+1 \mod n}$, $k=0,\dots,n-1$. We get: $\rho^i(a_j)=a_{j+i \mod n}=a_{i+j \mod n}=\rho^j(a_i)$; if we set $\gamma_i=\theta_i:=\rho^i$, both i) and ii) are fulfilled.  The (coincident) subgroups of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$, $\Theta=\lbrace \theta_i=\rho^i \rbrace$ and $\Gamma=\lbrace \gamma_i=\rho^i \rbrace$, define the (abelian) composition law $a_ia_j:=a_{j+i \mod n}$, whence $a_i^k=a_{ki \mod n}$ and then $a_1^k=a_{k \mod  n}=a_k$ for $k=0,\dots,n-1$. *[continues]*

Comment: Thus, $G=\lbrace a_k, k=0,...,n-1 \rbrace= \lbrace a_1^k, k=0,...,n-1 \rbrace= \langle a_1 \rangle$, and $G$ is cyclic. So we come up to cyclic group type. I was wondering whether this approach can be used to show other group types.

Comment: The best I can think of: If $\Theta$ is defined left multiplication in a group $G$, then $\Theta\cong G$ and $\Theta$ is regular, conversely if $\Theta$ is regular then it is a group of the same cardinality as $G$ so it is possible to impose a group structure on $G$ for which $\Theta$ is defined by left multiplication in $G$. So I guess the approach will work if and only if $\Theta$ (or indeed $\Gamma$) is regular

Comment: Do "regular" (@Robert Chamberlain) and "acting simply transitively" (@YCor) mean the same?

Comment: I believe they do

Comment: @YCor. "One way to make it work is to assume only (ii), and that the actions of both Θ and Γ are simply transitive. – YCor Mar 28 at 13:44": I think that the transitivity does hold, because the group is a group of bijections, while we have to assume the action to be free, in order to have it simply transitive. Am I wrong?