# Regular action vs. Transitive and Free

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on itself by multiplication by $g \in G$ on the left. I see that this action is free and transitive, thus regular.

Does the converse hold in general? Ie. if a group action is regular then it is multiplication on the left by some $g \in G$?

Comment: See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Regular_group_action

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without knowing more about what $G$ is and what $\Omega$ is. Are you imagining perhaps that $\Omega$ is some group and that $G$ is some subgroup? If so, please add that to your question. If not, please add to your question an explanation saying exactly what $G$ and $\Omega$ are.

Comment: @PawełCzyż so according to Wikipedia these are equivalent definitions. Can someone show why or gives hints on how to prove it?

Comment: "Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $Ω$ by multiplication by $g∈G$ on the left": this makes sense only if $G$ is a subgroup of $\Omega$. Unless by "multiplication by etc." you mean the usual way to writing *any* action, namely $g\cdot \omega$, but in this case you can't say anything about freeness etc. without further specifications.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited the question so that it now makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3165862/750041

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a group acting regularly on a set $\Omega$.
Choose $i\in \Omega$, and label $i$ with the identity of $G$. Now, for every  $\omega\in \Omega$, there is a unique $g\in G$ mapping $i$ to $\omega$. (This is more or less the definition of regular action.) Using this, we get a labelling of $\Omega$ with $G$, and it can easily be checked that what we get is the left-regular action (or right-regular, depending if it's a left or right action in the first place.)